# polyfills not being loaded in a symlinked child folder when running ng build

Tags: angular, webpack, symlink, polyfills

I have seen several issues raised on this topic, however this is unique because the errors are happening in a SYMLINKED repo. The parent repo loads polyfills correctly. I have already added polyfills in the parent webpack.config and I have ensured it is loaded (command below). Why is a symlinked child folder not using the polyfills?

parent folder runs this command:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --extra-webpack-config webpack.partial.js --configuration production
```

Error

```
../gk-datasync-pkg/node_modules/adm-zip/adm-zip.js:2:12-27 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\inven\Desktop\_REPOS\gk-datasync-frontend\gk-datasync-pkg\node_modules\adm-zip'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

webpack.partial

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
  //modules: [...],
  fallback: {
    "fs": false,
    "tls": false,
    .......
```